# Three minute payment confirmation url response delay for payment processor

Tags: drupal, payment-processor, mysql

I have a coop.symbiotic.moneticoclassique payment-processor set up and right now everything but the response to the payment gateway works.

1. The user pays for an item and is redirected to the payment gateway. When paying for the item, there is always a 30 second wait time for the payment to get approved.
2. The payment gateway then redirects the user back to the approved page showing the payment was successful.
3. The payment gateway then sends an email noting the successful payment that was made. However, about sixty seconds later another email arrives noting the payment was processed but the return_url had an error.

After some troubleshooting, I found that between step 1 and 2, the web server logs the HTTP 200 OK response to the payment gateway three minutes after the transaction has already been redirected to the thank you for your payment page. Does anyone know what possible causes CiviCRM would have to take 3 minutes to process the payment gateways request on the payment confirmation url?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what Payment Processor you’re working with

Comment: Updated question with the payment processor.

Comment: Ah best to check in with Mathieu/Samuel at coop.symbiotic.moneticoclassique - this is very much a specific to that payment processor question.